# Prove that if $f'$ is bounded and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)=0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ differentiable and $F$ one of its primitives. Prove that if $f'$ is bounded and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)=0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$. I found this problem too on mathstack but I can't find it. However, I wrote down the lemma that solves it, but I didn't understood it's proof. Can you give a proof for: Lemma: For $g:(a,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ double differentiable on $(a,\infty)$ with it's second derivative $g''$ bounded on $(a,\infty)$, if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=L$ then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}g'(x)=0$. For $F=g$ this solves our problem, but I don't know a proof for this lemma to the level of highschool maths.

Comment: See Littlewood's proof https://math.stackexchange.com/a/391864/72031

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)$ does not have to be $0$, it is okay with any $L=\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)$. Let $\delta>0$ be arbitrary and $|f'|\le M$. By mean value theorem, there is $s\in (0,1)$ and $s'\in (0,1)$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{F(x+\delta)-F(x)}{\delta}-f(x)\right|=\left|f(x+s\delta)-f(x)\right|=s\delta|f'(x+s'\delta)|\le M\delta.
$$ Let $x$ tend to $\infty$ to obtain
$$\begin{align*}
\limsup_{x\to\infty}\left|\frac{F(x+\delta)-F(x)}{\delta}-f(x)\right|&=\limsup_{x\to\infty}\left|f(x)\right|\le M\delta.
\end{align*}$$ Since $\delta>0$ is arbitrary, we get that
$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0.
$

Comment: Should your $f''$ not be $f'$?

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right. Thank you for the correction !

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that 
\begin{align}
\max|g'(t)|^2 \leq 4\left(\max|g(t)|\right) \left( \max|g''(t)|\right).
\end{align}
for any twice differentiable function on any interval $[a, b]$.

**Additional Hint to the Hint:** Observe
\begin{align}
g(t+2h) = g(t)+ 2g'(t)h+2g''(\xi)h^2
\end{align}
for some $\xi \in (t, t+2h)$. Hence it follows
\begin{align}
g'(t) = \frac{g(t+2h)-g(t)}{2h}-g''(\xi)h
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
|g'(t)| \leq \frac{\max |g(t)|}{h}+\max| g''(t)| h. 
\end{align}
Choose an appropriate $h$.

**Response to @MarkViola**: Consider the interval $(-1, \infty)$ and 
the function
\begin{align}
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x^2-1 & \text{ if } (-1<x<0),\\
\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1} & \text{ if } (0\leq x<\infty)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which is twice differentiable. Observe
\begin{align}
\sup |g(t)| = 1, \sup |g'(t)|=4, \text{ and } \sup |g''(t)|=4.
\end{align}
I stole this example from Baby Rudin Exercise 5.15.

Comment: Ops. I left the 4. Now it's correct.

Comment: In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125725/prove-that-left-fx-right-leq-sqrt2ac-using-integration/1579065#1579065), I showed that $|g'|\le \sqrt{2||g||_\infty\,||g''||_\infty}$.

Comment: Yes. I left the square yes well.

Comment: The $4$ is overkill.

Comment: @MarkViola I have updated my post.

Comment: If the interval on $\mathbb{R}$ is half closed or closed, then your bound is the tightest in general.  However, if you extend the interval to the entire real line, then a tighter bound (the one given [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125725/prove-that-left-fx-right-leq-sqrt2ac-using-integration/1579065#1579065)) exists.  It's rather interesting, is it not?

Comment: @MarkViola Yes. I absolutely agree with you on this.