# If $f$ is bounded and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} F(x)=0$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Let $f:(0, + \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a derivative function and $F$ one of its primitives. Prove that if $f$ is bounded and $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} F(x)=0$$ then $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=0$$

What I have tried:

I observed that $$(f(x)F(x))'=f'(x)F(x)+f^2(x)$$
It is obvious that the left term is $0$ when $x\rightarrow+\infty$. The problem is that we don't know that $f'$ is also bounded. If that would be the case, then $f'(x)F(x)\rightarrow 0$, so $f\rightarrow 0$.

Can you please help me solve this problem? Is it even correct or should $f'$ be bounded(instead of $f$)?

Comment: I think I'm missing something. If $f = \cos(x^2)$, and $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt - \sqrt{\frac\pi8}$, then $f$ is differentiable and bounded, and $F\to 0$, but $f\not\to 0$.

Comment: @Arthur Indeed, the statement is false.

Comment: Do you mean "Prove that if $f'$ is bounded and ..."? Because that seems more likely to be true. Besides, what else would be the point of requiring $f$ to be differentiable?

Comment: @Arthur That's how I found the problem stated, "$f$ bounded" and I also believe that it is not correct.

Comment: There was likely a typo.  See [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142083/prove-that-if-f-is-bounded-and-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-inftyfx-0-then?rq=1)