# Suppose that $|f(x)|\le1$ and $|f'''(x)|\le3$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $|f'(x)|\le 3/2$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion

I encountered this problem:
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is three times differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.
Suppose that $|f(x)|\le1$ and $|f'''(x)|\le3$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Prove that $|f'(x)|\le \frac{3}{2}$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. (Hint: Apply Taylor’s Theorem to f on $[x-h,x]$ and on $[x,x+h]$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $h>0$ .)

I think the main trick will be in both intervals; degree 2 is the same, so we can derive the inequality condition. However, I cannot figure out the correct way to use $|f(x)|\le1$ and $|f'''(x)|\le3$. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here's a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125725/prove-that-left-fx-right-leq-sqrt2ac-using-integration?noredirect=1) that should be of great assistance. You need to go one level deeper than the given question because you have $f'''$ instead of $f''$, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639970/functional-inequality-bounded-functions?noredirect=1).

Comment: All these estimates are particular cases of the [Landau–Kolmogorov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau–Kolmogorov_inequality).